# Kubernetes 1.2.2: api-server fails: can't find mounted certs for TLS on etcd

Tags: ssl, docker, kubernetes, coreos, etcd

I'm been struggling to get `api-server 1.2.2` to run with `etcd` secured with *TLS*.

I am upgrading from `1.1.2` to `1.2.2`

In `1.1.2` I was using the `--etcd-config` flag and had a file that looked like:

```
{
  "cluster": {
    "machines": [
      "https://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:2379",
      "https://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXY:2379",
      "https://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXZ:2379"
    ]
  },
  "config": {
    "certFile": "/etc/ssl/etcd/etcd-peer.cert.pem",
    "keyFile": "/etc/ssl/etcd/private/etcd-peer.key.pem",
    "caCertFiles": [
      "/etc/ssl/etcd/ca-chain.cert.pem"
    ],
    "consistency": "STRONG_CONSISTENCY"
  }
}
```

now this is no longer supported and I switched to using the flags:

```
--etcd-cafile="/etc/ssl/etcd/ca-chain.cert.pem"
--etcd-certfile="/etc/ssl/etcd/etcd-peer.cert.pem"
--etcd-keyfile="/etc/ssl/etcd/private/etcd-peer.key.pem"    
--etcd-servers="https://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:2379, https://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXY:2379,https://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXZ:2379"
```

now I am getting this error:

```
F0421 00:54:40.133777       1 server.go:291] Invalid storage version or misconfigured etcd: open "/etc/ssl/etcd/etcd-peer<nodeIP>.cert.pem": no such file or directory
```

So, it seems like it cannot find the cert file.
The file paths and names are the same as before, and they are mounted with `hostPath` the exact same way as with v1.1.2, so I don't understand why api-server would not not find them.

I have been trying to figure what is going on with the file paths by simply switching the `command` in the pod from

```
- /hyperkube
- api-server
...
```

to

```
- /bin/sleep
- 60
```

but `kubelet` won't start this pod for some reason I don't understand.

Does it have to do with the yaml file name or something?

I don't understand what is happening why `kubelet` won't run with this command.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I was able to get into the running container after replacing the command with `/hyperkube scheduler`

i can cat the files that apiserver is complaining about, so I don't understand why they're not found.

Comment: also reported here: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/24578 for cross-reference

Comment: I tried v1.2.1 and same problem. only 1.1.2 seems to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the culprit was as simple as ""

```
--etcd-cafile="/etc/ssl/etcd/ca-chain.cert.pem"
--etcd-certfile="/etc/ssl/etcd/etcd-peer.cert.pem"
--etcd-keyfile="/etc/ssl/etcd/private/etcd-peer.key.pem"    
--etcd-servers="https://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:2379, https://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXY:2379,https://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXZ:2379"
```

is WRONG

but this works:

```
--etcd-cafile=/etc/ssl/etcd/ca-chain.cert.pem
--etcd-certfile=/etc/ssl/etcd/etcd-peer.cert.pem
--etcd-keyfile=/etc/ssl/etcd/private/etcd-peer.key.pem   
--etcd-servers=https://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:2379,https://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXY:2379,https://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXZ:237
```

Comment: If you run those in a terminal, the shell helpfully removes the quotes for you, so the apiserver actually sees identical invocations for both. If you are launching from a non-shell environment (like args in a container's command array), you should leave out the quotes

Comment: thanks... it's good to know, but was unfortunately not obvious.